# LotusScript - How to send Doc link to document ready in Edit mode?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm modifying an old program in LotusNotes which have an agent to send document link to Approver email.

```
FIELD ForApprover1 := Approver;
FIELD ForApprover2 := Approver1;
FIELD AppInfo:= "Approver Info Locked";
FIELD submit:="submitted";
@If(Approver = "" & Approver1 = ""; @Do(@Command ([FileSave]);@Command([RunAgent] ;"sendmail");@SetField("ForApprover1";"Approval Locked");@SetField("ForApprover2";"Approval Locked"));Approver != "" & Status1 = ""; @Do(@MailSend(Approver; ""; ""; @Text(Subject) + " : Request To Approve : "+ @Text(docno)+@Text(dcounter); ""; "Double-click the document icon for Detail. ---> "; [IncludeDoclink]); FIELD ForApprover2:="Approval Locked");@Success);
@PostedCommand([FileSave]);
@PostedCommand([CloseWindow] )
```

The link will direct approver to the document in Read mode. Now I want to change it so that when approver clicks the link, it will direct them to Edit mode of the document instead of Read mode.

Is there a code which allows that?

EDIT:

I tried adding in code for QueryOpen event:

```
Sub Queryopen(Source As Notesuidocument, Mode As Integer, Isnewdoc As Variant, Continue As Variant)

Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set uidoc = w.CurrentDocument

 ' Get value for Approver 1 and 2

Approver_1 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Approver_1" )
Approver_2 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Approver_2" )
status1 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "status1" )
status2 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "status2" )
author = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Author" )
submit = uidoc.FieldGetText( "submit" ) 
cname = session.CommonUserName & "[redacted]"
aname = session.UserName

    'If Approver 1 hv not approve the form yet, let form open direct in Edit mode
If(Status1 <> "Yes" And cname = Approver_1) Then
    Call w.EditDocument (True)
End If

End Sub
```

But doing so will only create an error message `Object variable not set`.
What else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In the form's QueryOpen event, you can change the mode the form will be opened with. Check if the user is one of the approvers, and if so, open the document in Edit mode. Make sure you do this only once, e.g. by adding his name to a list of approvers who already opened the document this way.